# can't connect php to azure ms sql server database

Tags: php, sql-server, macos, azure, mamp

Does anyone know how to connect a php website to ms sql server database on azure?
Currently I'm using OSX Sierra 10.12.4, MAMP ver 4.1.1, and php7.1.1.

```
$serverName = "your_server.database.windows.net";
$connectionOptions = array(
"Database" => "your_database",
"Uid" => "your_username",
"PWD" => "your_password"
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
```

Im getting the error: 
    Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function       sqlsrv_connect()

does anyone know what packages I need to install?

Comment: Hav a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2010/02/12/getting-started-with-php-and-sql-azure/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you haven't installed Microsoft PHP drivers for SQL Server on your machine. The step by step installation instructions can be found in the Readme file: https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql

> Mac OS X
>
> ```
> brew tap microsoft/mssql-preview https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-preview
> brew update
> brew install msodbcsql
> brew install mssql-tools
> brew install autoconf
> ```

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I needed, it worked. Thanks!